# Connecting to Cloud SQL through deployed App Engine app (Different regions)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-sql

I currently have a deployed App Engine application (authorized through Cloud SQL) and in the same project as my Cloud SQL instance. I am using Python & Flask and follow the original Google code to connect to Cloud SQL.

```
if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine/'):
    try:
        return MySQLdb.connect(
             unix_socket='/cloudsql/{}:{}'.format(
                 CLOUDSQL_PROJECT,
                 CLOUDSQL_INSTANCE),
             user='root',
             db='my_db'
             )
    except:
        stacktrace = traceback.format_exc()
        logging.error("%s", stacktrace)
        return False
else:
    try:
        return MySQLdb.connect(host='xxx.xxx.xx.xx', 
                               user='root',
                               db='my_db',
                               passwd='password',
                               port=3306)
    except:
        return False
```

When running on the local devserver everything is fine but since deployment I have not been able to connect to Cloud SQL. This is the error I get:

```
OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 38")
```

I have checked multiple times that the two variables CLOUDSQL_PROJECT & CLOUDSQL_INSTANCE are configured correctly.
I have also tried connecting without specifying db, with/without specifying password and so on. 
One potential issue could be the fact that our App Engine instance is in us-central(to be changed) and our Cloud SQL is in euro-west. I was wondering if that could be the source of the problem since I do not see anything else that could be causing this error or am I making a mistake somewhere else.

Thank you for your time and advice.
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/app-engine-connect, the GAE app needs to be in the same region as the Cloud SQL instance.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response! From that page I gathered that this only applied to App Engine (standard env.) to First Generation Cloud SQL). I forgot to mention that ours was App Engine (standard env.) to Second Generation Cloud SQL (currently in beta) and there was no specific region information there. Do you think this is still the issue?

Comment: While I think it might work at the moment, it's not a configuration I would encourage. Having your app and database in different regions will not perform well.

Comment: I spent a couple more days trying to work around this issue, however, I did not have much success with that, so I figured that it is not possible to connect an App Engine app and a Cloud SQL instances in different regions. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can setup a proxy server that directs traffic from app engine region to cloud sql region and that can stay internal only. Also you can access mysql using internal ip . We are using this kind of setup in one of the production setup but instead of cloud sql we have elastic search in different region and accessing over private ip space.